# Stack buffer overflow but my program is working. Why?

Tags: arrays, c, buffer-overflow

I've got a problem with my program.
This program takes as an input users IDs ( e.g + 10 ) and the shows how many visits had this ID made and as output it shows the number of the visit. Or the program takes ? as the input followed by e.g. 12/20, which will output the number of unique users in the range of their visit from 12 to 20.
Now to the problem, the program works well, except that the debbuger is warning me, that there is a stack-buffer-overflow and I just dont quite understand it. Can somebody please explain, where i have is it overflowing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define USERS_MAX 100000
#define VISIT_MAX 1000000

/*
* Retuerns how many IDs from range k - l are unique
*/

int CompareArray ( const int * a, int min, int max )
{
   int i, j, uniqusers = 0;
   for ( i = min; i <= max; i++ )
   {
      for ( j = min; j <= max; j++ )
      {
         if ( a[i] == a[j] )
         {
            break;
         }
      }
      if ( j < i )
      {
         continue;
      }
      uniqusers ++;
   }
   return uniqusers;
}

int main ( void )
{
   int userslogginrank[VISIT_MAX];
   int usersvisitations[USERS_MAX];
   int i = 0, end = 0, k, l;
   char sign;
   printf ( "Requirements:\n" );
   do 
   {
      if ( 1 != scanf ( "%s", &sign ) )
      {
         if ( feof ( stdin ) )
         {
            end = 1;
            return 1;
         }
         else
         {
            printf ( "Wrong input.\n" );
            return 1;
         }   
      }
      else
      {      
      switch ( sign )
      {
         case '+':
         {
 
            if ( 1 != scanf ( " %d", &l ) || l < 0 || l > 99999 )
            {
               printf ( "Wrong input.\n" );
               end = 1;
               return 1;
            }
            else 
            {
               userslogginrank[i] = l;
               usersvisitations[l] ++;
               i++;
               if ( usersvisitations[l] == 1 )
               {
                  printf ( "> first visit\n" );
               }
               else
               {
                  printf ( "> visit #%d\n", usersvisitations[l] );
               }
            }
            break;
         }
         case '?':
         {
            if ( 2 != scanf ( " %d %d", &k, &l ) || k > l || l >= i  || k < 0 )
            {
               printf ( "Wrong input.\n" );
               end = 1;
               return 1;
            }
            else
            {
               printf ( "> %d / %d\n", CompareArray ( userslogginrank, k, l ), l - k + 1 );
            }
            break;
            
         } 
         default :
         {
            scanf ( "%d", &k );
            printf ( "Wrong input.\n");
            end = 1;
            return 1;
         }
      }
      }
   } while ( end != 1 || i <= 999999 );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the stack overflow is because of the large local arrays. You can dynamically allocate them instead.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &sign)` is incorrect - a string is expected not a `char`. It should be `scanf(" %c", &sign)`

Comment: You should include what the compiler or debugger tells you in your question. If it tells you there is a buffer overflow, it also should tell you where, shouldn't it?